# Change form button class depending on field input

Tags: wordpress

I have a button in a form that has the class "popmake-46". The class makes it so that if the button is clicked a popup window opens. However, I want to make it so that the class changes to a different class (different popup) depending on the input of "zipcode".

If the zipcode starts with the numbers "117", the class should remain as "popmake-46", but if it starts with any other number, it should change the class to "popmake-47" (different popup window).

```
<form name="form1">
 <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"><br>
 <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode"><br>
 <input class="popmake-46" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is WordPress specific, it seems you just need to add an [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) and/or [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) event handler to your `zipcode` field.

I'm not sure of how you're implementing this form exactly, so here's a pretty basic way to do it:

- Create a function that checks the value of the current element
- If the value starts with '117' add the `-47` class and remove the `-46` class
- Otherwise remove the `-47` class and add the `-46` class back.
- add that function to the `onchange` and/or `onkeyup` event for the zip code.

In the snippet below I've added a little CSS (and changed your submit input to a button so I could use the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) CSS pseudo-class to illustrate that it's changing based on what class it currently is.

```js
function toggle46or47(el){
  var form = el.closest('form');
  var popMake = form.querySelector('[type="submit"]');
  
  if( el.value.substring(0, 3) == '117' ){
    popMake.classList.remove('popmake-46');
    popMake.classList.add('popmake-47');
  } else {
    popMake.classList.add('popmake-46');
    popMake.classList.remove('popmake-47');
  }
}
```

```css
.popmake-46:after{content: " I'm 46";}.popmake-47:after{content: " I'm 47";}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
 <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"><br>
 <input type="text" onchange="toggle46or47(this);" onkeyup="toggle46or47(this);" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode"><br>
 <button class="popmake-46" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Very awesome. This has helped me a lot. Blessed. :)